25A SSR Failing
I have a 25A soild state relay I'm using to control a boiler. Using a SSR-25 DA https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/SSR40DA.pdf. The issue I have is that if I supply 12v to the input after about a min or so it makes an audible click then stops conducting on the AC side, the LED is still illuminated. If I disconnect the AC side I again hear a click and after reconnecting it works fine, so long as the duty cycle is less than one min. The AC is 120V at around 10-12A. I tried reversing what terminals the load and source were connected to on the AC side but no luck. Maybe it's just a bad SSR? When it goes into this state the SSR does not heat up.

I know you say it isn't heating up. But you don't know for sure what's taking place at the critical IC dice. And it sounds as though it is shutting down for thermal reasons. What are the boiler details and the rest of your circuit arrangement? It may help to know.

@periblepsis its a simple circuit just 12v DC going to the input side, controlled with a switch, on the AC side I just have the load line going to one SSR PIN and the other pin going to the boiler, the other wire from the boiler goes to the neutral line. The boiler is a 1200W AC heating element about 12ohms.

Okay. So it's only about 10 A then for the boiler. Just wanted to be sure. In that case, I don't have a specific suggestion to resolve this. Is there a heat sink with the SSR? About 2 V and 10 A means about 20 W. So just want to check on that, too.

Sounds like it's overheating. How do you cool it?

Even mounting it on the heatsink shown in the datasheet is marginal. Maximum current for the single SSR model is 10A equating to 16W. Operating at the absolute maximum rating is never a good idea and little things like bad thermal interface, insufficient mounting screw torque, or orientation can lead to problems.

An audible click? That's unusual for an SSR. Either there's a backup mechanical relay or thermoswitch in there that's cutting the output in an overcurrent/overtemperature condition (seems pretty unlikely to me--that would probably be mentioned on the datasheet--but who knows), or something's breaking.

The Fotek datasheet on their website shows overtemperature protection at 120°C as a feature of their SSR-25DA. That's higher than I would want to run them for reliability, incidentally.

There are also heat sink and fan recommendations but the model numbers are a bit of a mishmash and they don't give Ta numbers so I didn't think it was worth fully pursuing, however you will need a substantial heat sink with thermal compound between the SSR and heatsink, and maybe a fan. Dissipation will be in the 10-15W range.
Sounds like they've included a self-resetting bimetal thermal cutoff and it is saving your bacon.
You also need to be a bit careful, there are fake Fotek SSRs about, but the thermal cutoff is exactly the kind of thing they would leave out.

Hi Spehro - Re: "there are fake Fotek SSRs about, but the thermal cutoff is exactly the kind of thing they would leave out." Exactly right. The fake one I was asked to dismantle didn't have anything like that inside :(

The voltage drop is 1.6V so at 10 amps you have 16 watts of heat to deal with. Without a good heat sink the temperature will go through the roof.

@QTX it's not usually quite that bad. Should be closer to 10W typically from the triac with 10A RMS resistive and a 25A rated triac. See Fig 1. For one thing, the voltage drop is less when Tj >> 25°C. There is, however, some additional loss in the connections (and overtemperature switch) in the packaged SSR.
